# jquery or js Event Handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, event-handling

I'm wondering given both the native js and jquery event handler, which one should I choose for a memory consumption/performance standpoint? Say I have this html code, a simple button.

```
<button id="herp">derp</button>
```

Would

```
herp.onclick = function()
{
    alert('hey');
}
```

be better than

```
$("#herp").click(function()
{
    alert('hey');
});
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notwithstanding this being evil premature micro-optimisation -

1. jQuery wraps native events quite heavily to normalise browser compatibility issues, so will always be (slightly) slower
2. DOM3 style `addEventListener` should be preferred to DOM0 `.onxxx`, but not for any performance or memory reason that I know of

Comment: Which browsers would not be compatible with onclick, onkeypress, etc? Are there any other benefits to using jquery event handlers?

Comment: @7ch5 all browsers support `.onXXX`, but there are things you can do with (native) `addEventListener` that you can't do with `.onXXX`.

Answer (score 1):

Analyze the difference. If you're only doing it once and you can't even tell the difference then it doesn't matter.

If you do it one million times see what the difference in speed and memory consumption is and decide.

Try to avoid premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If the page already includes jQuery for other reasons, then adding one event handler is not going to make any significant difference in memory consumption/performance.

On the other hand, if the page does not need jQuery for any other reason, then a page without jQuery will be smaller/faster.